# How to retrieve date from an excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an Excel Sheet with  dates: `4/8/2015` and `6/7/2015` in the same column.

I want to display these dates in console using Apache POI

I tried this code:

```
Date date1=cell.getDateCellValue();
System.out.println(date1);
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(date1);
```

But it is displaying dates in some other format like 42102.0 42162.0

How can i get the same dates in console..

Comment: What happens if you try using [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
         String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
          if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
               // format in form of M/D/YY
              double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

              Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
              cellText =
                 (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
              cellText = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                          cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" + 
                          cellText;

              System.out.println(cellText);

             }
```